# Convert MySQL decimal number to kilogram unit

Tags: mysql

I add `length` name with `decimal (15,8)` type in MySQL database. Now I have `12.00000000` and need to convert to meter unit like `12`. How do can I convert this?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on cast and convert - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html

for your example

```
select cast(12.00000000 as unsigned)

+-------------------------------+
| cast(12.00000000 as unsigned) |
+-------------------------------+
|                            12 |
+-------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is somewhat complicated.

The first option is to use [CAST](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html)

But this causes Rounding of the value, if you don_'t want that, you have to convert intgo a String and use substring_I'NDEX

> ```
> CREATE TABLE table1 (
>   `value` DECIMAL(15,8)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO table1
>   ( `value`)
> VALUES
>   (12.00001),
>   (12.50001);
> ```

> ```
> SELECT CAST(value as unsigned) FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> | CAST(value as unsigned) |
> | ----------------------: |
> |                      12 |
> |                      13 |
> ```

> ```
> SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONVERT(value, CHAR),'.',1) FROM table1
> ```
>
> ```
> | SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONVERT(value, CHAR),'.',1) |
> | :------------------------------------------ |
> | 12                                          |
> | 12                                          |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3cfd4f85cd5f635207eed159531da134)*